# SQL Query interface to database

Tags: sql, database, interface

My development team if offshore and host work on a test site. I want them to create an interface on the test site where I can run SQL queries to check data in the database (so all reads) + be able to load in lookup values / create tables etc (Writes) via the interface.

I see stackoverflow has something similar with its data explorer were we can do reads on the data via custom queries. I need the same thing + need to write also.

So the question is: How to create this interface? It is a plug-in, readymade, open source or needs to be done from scratch?

I am using PHP codeignitor & MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just install [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)?

ETA:

Here's a url with a [demo of phpMyAdmin](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/).  Login with user `root` and empty password.

Comment: phpmyadmin will be local to my pc. I need to access the Database which is remote on the test webserver. Plus anyways I need an admin interface to the database once the site is live to read from the DB with ease like SO does it with their data exchange.

Comment: @Rohit: phpMyAdmin is installed on the remote server.

Comment: So i ask my team to install phpmyadmin on the webserver? But how do i query the database from it from my home pc?

Comment: @Rohit - It's a web based database administration tool.  You go to a URL, log in with a MySQL username and password, and you can issue SQL queries against the database.